# Validation.HasError and custom ToolTip

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm setting extra ToolTip for a field with errors in ResourceDictionary

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I also defined special style for this tooltip, which simulate the one on red triangle in right upper corner

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Right"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalOffset" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        Background="Red"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="5 2 5 3" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Opened">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard TargetProperty="HorizontalOffset">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="5" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Everything works, but now ALL ToolTips have this style.

Is it possible to achieve that ToolTip style take his part only if Validation.HasError occurs? I can as x:Key, but how to apply that to Style.Triggers part?

Because I have this ToolTip defined also on other controls I wouldn't like to copy all this code multiple times, but if only that is a solution I will do so :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another couple of hours of Googling I try the solution provided here 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10d2ecbf-9e6e-4414-b57e-79dd02e0944e/changing-style-of-tooltip-in-textbox

and it works!

A created ToolTip style

```
<ToolTip x:Key="ErrorToolTip" 
         Placement="Right" 
         Background="Red" 
         Foreground="White" 
         BorderThickness="0" 
         DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <ToolTip.Content>
        <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent"/>
    </ToolTip.Content>
    <ToolTip.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToolTip.Opened">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard TargetProperty="HorizontalOffset">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="5" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ToolTip.Triggers>
</ToolTip>
```

and changed Style.Triggers to

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource ErrorToolTip}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Need to do some more styling, but it's OK for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property `Validation.ErrorTemplate` on the `TextBox` style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">    
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
                Value="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However, this way you can't work with a `ToolTip` style, but you have to work with a template and a `x:Key`.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
      <Border Name="Border"
              Background="Red"
              Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
              Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
           <ContentPresenter Margin="5 2 5 3" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      </Border>
      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Opened">
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetProperty="HorizontalOffset">
                              <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="5" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
       </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: This approach replace default ErrorTemplate what I don't want. I just want to add ToolTip when TextBox (or any other editor) has Validation Error. Is that possible to achieve?